# How can i specify a discord text channel in my code?

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to specify a channel to send a message in. The code below doesn't work.

```
async def on_message(ctx):   
    if channel == 793261911411654669 and ctx.author.id == 418643244284287024:
```

Is there a proper way to define the channel in this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `ctx.channel.id` to get the ID of the channel that the message was sent in.

So, your event would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):   
    if ctx.channel.id == 793261911411654669 and ctx.author.id == 418643244284287024:
        await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

This event will run the defined commands only if the condition is `True`.